# Как восстановить проект из GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Ну точнее как восстановить чтобы он работал с GitHub.

Ситуация такая: Есть мой проект на GitHub; пароль и логин есть, могу заходить. Но на жестком диске проекта с папкой git нету, все удалено, все настройки связи с GitHub конечно слетели.

Как мне из GitHub сделать настройку чтобы проект был связан с GitHub, чтобы можно было туда коммитится? Ну чтобы все работало как раньше. Работаю с Qt

Comment: Открыть терминал, зайти в свою папку куда хотим склонировать репо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то должно помочь:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/projectname.git
```

> как мне из git-hub сделать настройку чтобы проект был связан с git-hub

Вот эта фраза непонятна

Comment: Я думаю он хочет чтобы remote добавился. Он добавится автоматически при клонировании как вы указали

Comment: Да все получилось, спс большое. Я просто практически не работал с git-hub.